Why is the time one hour off even though the correct time zone seem to be recognized?

On my Windows 11 with ntp enabled and my timezone automatically correctly identified as "Stockholm" but not properly identified as "summer time" the time is one hour off. How can I set that right?
Disabling automatic time zone identification still won't let me select timezone or verify if daylight savings time is honored:

Looking at the setting with tzutil verifies that dst is indeed disabled:
C:\Users\azzid>tzutil /g
W. Europe Standard Time_dstoff

Even though no such toggle appear in the settings dialogue.

The two time zones are NOT identical.  One is UTC+2 the other is UTC+1 pick the same time zone. Which one is correct, I don't know, your screenshots are not in English.

You do realize Stockholm is only in one timezone? Windows is probably failing to recognize that it is currently summer time. Also, the OS selects the zone, not me.

Timezones work like this. When you have summertime, you move to a different timezone. So Stockholm will be UTC+1 in the winter, and UTC+2 in the summer.

I've been through a fair share of computers - never have I been expected to manually toggle time between winter and summer - should I really need to on this one?

@azzid you shouldn't have to, but the setting to do it automatically may have been disabled for some reason, see the edit to my answer.

@azzid - I live in a region where it's either CST or CDT.  You asked why it was different, I explained, that your comparison between the google result and the time zone selected within Windows is not identical. Windows uses geolocation to determine your location. Microsoft probably has to send an update. I remember some news on some updated region files back in March timeframe causing an incorrect time adjustment.

The change happened back in January..


Using tzutil the dst-toggle that seem to be missing from the settings can be switched.
Clock is okay after; even when ntp and tz-detection is re-enabled.

Unselect "Ange tidszon automatiskt" (Set Timezone Automatically) you then need to do two things

Make sure you have set the correct timezone.

Also make sure that your equivalent of "Adjust for daylight saving time automatically" is selected.



You may be able to reselect "set the timezone automatically" if daylight savings is now enabled when it was not.
As Ramhound says in a comment Google claims you are UTC+2 while Windows claims it is UTC+1. During summer Sweden time should be operating at UTC+2 while in winter it should be UTC+1.
From Wikipedia

In Sweden, the standard time is Central European Time (CET; UTC+01:00; Swedish: centraleuropeisk tid).1 Daylight saving time is observed from the last Sunday in March (02:00 CET) to the last Sunday in October (03:00 CEST).

The observance of DST would change UTC+01 to UTC+02
It is possible that Windows does not have the correct settings for your region.

Disabling the auto selection still does not allow me to select the time zone, and even if I was allowed to select the tz I don't believe there to be a "Stockholm, UTC+2" to choose from.

Is there an "automatically adjust for daylight savings" setting under there that can be toggled?

Not that I've been able to find - that's why the question is posted here. ;-)

@azzid if you turn off "Ange tidszon automatiskt" do you get this new option? https://i.sstatic.net/J9zm8R2C.png If so then make sure it is turned on. I have edited my answer.

@azzid - It's become clear that is your actual question but that most certainly is NOT what you asked.

@Mokubai - I don't see the same settings you do. In particular I am unable to change timezone at all. Will update post with pictures.
